# Can a C++ object be stored at the highest memory-location?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object, byte

Is the highest memory-location (probably `(void*)(std::uintptr_t)-1`) a valid address for storing a C++ object?

Comment: `.begin()` and `.end()` are iterators, they have nothing (necessarily) to do with `size_t`

Comment: "less than" means "call the overloaded function `vector::iterator::operator<`" , and this might know about the possibility of the last element being in the highest memory address and return the correct result

Comment: This is a different question for `vector` than other containers; vectors require elements to be stored in contiguous memory and others don't

Comment: @Matt McNabb that's a good point, thanks

Comment: C-style arrays typically wouldn't use up the last memory location though, as it is too much hassle for the compiler to support having the one-past-the-end pointer be greater than an earlier pointer

Comment: In what sense is `size_t max ((size_t)-1)` a memory location, other than being an object of type `size_t` with a presumably irrelevant initial value? A value of type `size_t` is an integer value, not a pointer or address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vect.end()` is never smaller than `vect.begin()`. They are equal iff `vect.empty()`.

`(void*)(uintptr_t)-1` (which is usually the same as `(void*)(size_t)-1`) points to the largest addressable byte of virtual memory. Depending on the architecture and the environment, it can be a valid or an invalid memory location.

The last element of the vector (`*(vect.end() - 1)`) can reside on the largest virtual memory address.

Comment: so can the last element of a vector never reside in the highest memory address?

Comment: @jayjay Just so you are aware, `.end()` does *not* point at the last element in the `vector`, it points past the end of the `vector`

Comment: @Cyber: I think that's the OP's point (that's clearer now they've reworded the question).

Comment: @pts: You sure that would point there? Where is that guarantee?

Comment: @Deduplicator: What do you think the largest addressable byte of virtual memory is, if it's not `(void*)(size_t)-1`? Nevertheless, I've added *typically*.

Comment: Possibly `(void*)(uintptr_t)-1`? Still, the mapping is not specified, so even my expression might not point there.

Comment: @pts I think size_t is guaranteed to index all memory, memory is not guaranteed to fill size_t

Comment: @pts: I think the point is, there is no guaranteed relationship between the size of the address space and the size of a `size_t`. Canonical example: address space on x86-64 is 48-bit (although due to overflow, -1 would still happen to map to the max address).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've rephrased my answer using `uintptr_t`.

Comment: `size_t` is not guaranteed to index all memory, `uintptr_t` is. `size_t` is only specified to store all possible byte-indices into every object, and can thus be considerably smaller.

Comment: I concurr with all but your last statement. For determining whether it can reside at the highest address, you must first prove any valid C++ object may reside there. I'm not sure that's the case though... neither am I that sure it's not.

Comment: Your statement about `(void*)(uintptr_t)-1` assumes, among other things, that addresses are unsigned. As far as the language is concerned, address have no signedness, simply because they're not integers.

Comment: `uintptr_t` is not even guaranteed to exist

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no guarantee that address -1 is invalid. However, it is the highest possible address.

Of course, iterators doesn't have any bearing on valid memory addresses or the values of `size_t`. Just that they compare in a sane way using the `operator<(iterator, iterator)`. And of course, if `v.begin()` is `-1`, then `v.end()` can't be higher than `v.begin()`, since it is by definition the HIGHEST address that can be used in the machine - one byte beyond that is 0, which is at the lowest address of memory.

I very much doubt that you could actually contrive such a situation, but technically, assuming iterators actualy are implemented as pointers, if you have `vector<char>`, and manage to allocate a pointer at exactly `-1`, then `v.end()` would actually be zero. However, you would REALLY have to work at it, since that memory is typically reserved for kernel space (and probably protected by the OS to detect "negative offset into NULL pointer objects").

So whilst there is no guarantee that this can't happen, in practice it's pretty much certain it will not happen by the design of the system.

Edit based on reformulated question:

The C++ standard does not preclude the highest available address from being used. But like the above text says, you'd have to work pretty hard to actually use it in a system that is based on a modern processor and has a modern OS (Linux, Windows and such like), as the memory range is reserved to catch "bad NULL pointer access".

Comment: You sure any old iterator is `LessThanComparable`?

Comment: Well, technically they don't have, to be, but it's kind of unpractical when they aren't...

Comment: All but RandomAccessIterator`s are only `EqualityComparable`, doesn't mean that's not useful.